# What is a good way to write a function to load multiple years of data - each in its own file - as a function?

Tags: r, dataframe, function

The code I have works but I can't help but think there is a much more efficient way to write it. Essentially the function I would want to write would output the df variable.

```
read_data_raw<- function(y1,y2) {
  raw_scores_y1_y2 <- read.csv(paste0("raw_scores_",y1,"_",y2,".txt"))
  return(raw_scores_y1_y2)
}


read_data_vegas<- function(y1,y2) {
  vegas_y1_y2 <- read.csv(paste0("vegas_",y1,"_",y2,".txt"))
  return(vegas_y1_y2)
}



raw_scores <- read_data_raw(12,13)
vegas <- read_data_vegas(12,13)
df <- inner_join(raw_scores,vegas, by = c("TEAM_ID" = "TeamId","GAME_ID"="GameId" ) )
raw_scores <- read_data_raw(13,14)
vegas <- read_data_vegas(13,14)
df2 <- inner_join(raw_scores,vegas, by = c("TEAM_ID" = "TeamId","GAME_ID"="GameId" ) )
df <- rbind(df,df2)
raw_scores <- read_data_raw(14,15)
vegas <- read_data_vegas(14,15)
df2 <- inner_join(raw_scores,vegas, by = c("TEAM_ID" = "TeamId","GAME_ID"="GameId" ) )
df <- rbind(df,df2)
raw_scores <- read_data_raw(15,16)
vegas <- read_data_vegas(15,16)
df2 <- inner_join(raw_scores,vegas, by = c("TEAM_ID" = "TeamId","GAME_ID"="GameId" ) )
df <- rbind(df,df2)
raw_scores <- read_data_raw(16,17)
vegas <- read_data_vegas(16,17)
df2 <- inner_join(raw_scores,vegas, by = c("TEAM_ID" = "TeamId","GAME_ID"="GameId" ) )
df <- rbind(df,df2)
raw_scores <- read_data_raw(17,18)
vegas <- read_data_vegas(17,18)
df2 <- inner_join(raw_scores,vegas, by = c("TEAM_ID" = "TeamId","GAME_ID"="GameId" ) )
df <- rbind(df,df2)
raw_scores <- read_data_raw(18,19)
vegas <- read_data_vegas(18,19)
df2 <- inner_join(raw_scores,vegas, by = c("TEAM_ID" = "TeamId","GAME_ID"="GameId" ) )
df <- rbind(df,df2)
```

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. Right now we don't have your data or know much of anything about it or what your goal is exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `purrr::map_df` to perform inner join and combine all the dataframes into one.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

vals <- 12:18
df <- map_df(vals, 
             ~inner_join(read_data_raw(.x,.x + 1), 
                         read_data_vegas(.x,.x + 1),
                          by = c("TEAM_ID" = "TeamId","GAME_ID"="GameId")))
```